# shinyio is not displaying words that contains stress

Tags: r, publishing, shiny, display

I am a brazilian student and I am publishing the App in two languages: english and portuguese. However, when I publish the app and select portuguese, all the words that come with stresses are not displayed. Ex.: Trees (english) Árvores (correct portuguese) , how it is being displayed: rvores.  The weird thing is that in R console it displays the word correctly but when I publish it all the letters with stress are not displayed. 
I tried to save the files with encode UTF 8 but did not have success.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

I really appreciate! 
Best,

Comment: Did you already try if this: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/unicode-characters.html could help?

Comment: Hey you! The thing is that RStudio displays everything perfectly, the issue is that shinyio server that is not supporting the foreign characters... Do you if there's any codes that I need to write in order to display stresses in words correctly in shinyio when publishing the App? Thanks a lot!

Comment: the link is for shiny. so that didnt work out? Then provide us with a reproducible example.

Comment: Could you please send a Hi on my email? iasmimlouriiene@gmail.com. Then I share all the files with you!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: https://iaslouriene.shinyapps.io/IndivTreeDetecLiDAR/ 

Detecção de árvores individuais em dados LiDAR  - displayed in RStudio 

Deteco de rvores individuais em dados LiDAR  - displayed in shinyio

Comment: My idea was to use the code in the link i provided, i still dont know whether u tried that,... Good luck anyway or maybe smbdy else can help.